# Keep animation playing until it finished on unhover in CSS

Tags: css

So i have this block of code that makes an animation:

```css
.c:hover{
    animation: rotate 1s ease;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    } to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Basically i want the animation to keep playing even after `unhover` until it ends

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you'll need some javascript to set the animation going and to wait for animationend - is that acceptable? However, is the animation you require as simple as it seems and do you want fill-mode forwards?

Comment: @AHaworth Nope thats it the animation i am using. I will try with javascript

Comment: @AHaworth Yep, it worked with a little bit of javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution, I used JavaScript to remove the animation after the time has passed.

```js
const animated = document.getElementById('c');

animated.onmouseenter = () => {
  // Need to remove the animation after its done, otherwise
  // It won't play again when the mouse is hovering on the element.
  setTimeout(() => animated.style.animation = '', 1000);

  animated.style.animation = 'rotate 1s ease';
}
```